# Unit test classes inside functions.php in Wordpress using PHPUnit

Tags: php, wordpress, unit-testing

I am new to Wordpress.
I have already a Wordpress with PHPUnit already installed.
If I will create a custom theme, I can write a class inside functions.php file.

My question is how can I write unit test using PHPUnit wherein my Wordpress class file are located in functions.php?

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-beginners-guide-to-unit-testing-building-a-testable-plugin--wp-25741 you need to create a new test class, that tests the functions within that file. This guide should put you on track

Comment: i mean not testing a plugin or theme. a php class which resides inside functions.php of a custom theme